# python list() removing entire list when nested with another operation in ipython notebook

Tags: python, list, ipython

I am trying to get list of column headers from a panda data frame. I also want to remove one unwanted element in the list. I tried below code, and that works.

```
features_list = list(data_panda.columns.values)
features_list.remove('email_address')
features_list
```

**Output**: *produces the list*

But when I try to do that in single line as below, I get nothing as output.

```
features_list_1 = list(data_panda.columns.values).remove('email_address')
features_list_1
```

**Output**: *Nothing*

**Screenshot**:
[image]

Why?

I am using Py2 environment in Anaconda.

Comment: Because `remove` works in-place and returns `None`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.remove()` modifies the original list in place, it does not return anything. Which is why `features_list_1` was None, since that's the default when nothing is returned.

---

If you want to do it in one line, you cannot use `.remove()`, instead create a *new* list with a list comprehension.

```
features_list = [x for x in data_panda.columns.values if x != 'email_address']
```

But unlike `remove`, this will remove all occurrences of `'email_address'`, whereas `remove` only removes the first.

---

The following will work like a single lined `.remove()` (only removing the first occurrence) without using semi-colons (since that's just cheating). But *please, please don't do this...* write it the normal way.

```
features_list = (lambda y=set(): [x for x in data_panda.columns.values if y or (x != 'email_address' or y.add(0))])()
```